# Adjusting value of a discriminated union object

Tags: f#

So, yet another discriminated union question :-)

Assume I have a discriminated union like so:-

```
type Foo =
  | A of string
  | B of int
  | C of char
  | D of string
```

I would like to be able to use a function, appendStringToFoo, as follows:-

```
let someVal = A("hi")
let anotherVal = D("yo")

let hiya = someVal |> appendStringToFoo "ya"
let yoyo = anotherVal |> appendStringToFoo "yo"
```

Where hiya = A("hiya")
and yoyo = D("yoyo").

Obviously, I'd also go on to write separate functions appendIntToFoo, appendCharToFoo, etc.

So, effectively, a function similar to:-

```
let appendStringToFoo str fooValue =
  fooValue(fooValue.Value + str)
```

Which doesn't seem possible.

I *do not* want to do the following if I can avoid it:-

```
let appendStringToFoo str fooValue =
    match fooValue with
    | A(originalStr) -> A(originalStr + str)
    | D(originalStr) -> D(originalStr + str)
```

As that means I'd have to re-write this code every time I added a new union case.

Any ideas?

Comment: What behavior do you want for appendStringToFoo "x" (B(42))?  Overall this smells to me, what are you really trying to do (what are Foo/A/B)?

Comment: In general, "every time you add a new union case" you must rewrite all the code in the world that uses that union type.  This is a trade-off between using discriminated unions and using class hierarchies.

Comment: This is part of a lexer; I am constructing a string from characters which is being placed in a discriminated union representation of a token.

Comment: I have refactored this anyway (yes, it does smell!). In answer to your question I had intended such situations to result in some kind of exception; however, on reflection, it seems rather un-type safe. Now I have the problem of wanting to match on an 'a -> DiscrimUnion again...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the thing you don't want to do.

An alternative would be along the lines of

- abstract class Foo
- abstract class StringyFoo : Foo { void AppendString(string); string S; }
- class A : StringyFoo
- class D : StringyFoo
- abstract class IntyFoo : Foo
- class B : IntyFoo

which potentially avoids 'fixing up appendString() each time you add a new token type', but I think that for a lexer (where Foo=Token) you'll be happier overall with the DU.

In general with lexing/parsing, whether you use class hierarchies and the Visitor pattern, or you use algebraic data types, you always must write N*M code for N features and M subtypes; there's no avoiding it, so don't bother trying to find cute tricks to try to avoid it, it only leads to misery.

Comment: Sound advice. I guess I'm just gonna learn a lot of this stuff the hard way...!